# Conditions for tensor product of fields to be a field

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field, tensor-products

Suppose $k$ is a field of characteristic 0. $L/k$ is any field extension, $K/k$ is a finite extension (not assumed to be Galois). If we know that $L\otimes_k K$ is not a field, can we conclude that there exists a finite subextension $L_0/k$ inside $L/k$ such that $L_0\otimes_k K$ is not a field as well?

Comment: Let's rephrase it: suppose for every finite $L_0\subset L$, $L_0\otimes_k K$ is a field. Could you then conclude that $L\otimes_k K$ is a field?

Comment: It's true if $L/k$ is algebraic and I encourage you to convince yourself of this on the basis that $L\otimes_kK$ is the "union" (directed colimit, if that means something to you) of $L_0\otimes_kK$ over all finite subextensions $L/L_0/k$. I'm not so sure what happens if $L/k$ has positive transcendence degree (of course, for purely transcendental extensions, we always get fields, but what happens if there's an algebraic part above a purely transcendental part...).

Comment: @Captain Lama Thanks a lot! Your reformulation is much more clear!

Comment: @Thorgott I come up with an idea and post it as an answer below. I’m not sure if it works.

Comment: @Thorgott Even if it’s correct. I still believe this purely field-theoretic problem should have a purely field-theoretic solution:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(By the primitive element theorem) $K=k(\alpha) \cong k[x]/(f)$ with $f$ monic irreducible

That $L\otimes_k K\cong L[x]/(f)$ is not a field means that $f$ is not irreducible over $L$.

ie. $f= gh$ with $g,h\in L[x]_{monic}$.

The coefficients of $g,h$ are algebraic over $k$ so they lie in a finite extension $E/k,E\subset L$.

and $E\otimes_k K \cong E[x]/(f)$ is not a field.

---

The primitive element theorem is not really needed because if $K=k(\alpha,\beta)$ then $L\otimes_k K= (L\otimes_k k(\alpha))\otimes_{k(\alpha)} K$

Comment: As I had to take a couple of minutes to convince myself that the coefficients of $g$ and $h$ are indeed algebraic over $k$, I'll write an argument in case someone else is not seeing it immediately: the coefficients of $g$ are polynomial functions of its roots (in some splitting field), but its roots are also roots of $f$, so they are algebraic over $k$.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I did try to think of an argument like this but got stuck in the case that the coefficient of $g,h$ are not algebraic. I didn’t notice that it can’t happen!

Answer (score 0):

I think maybe the following argument works. Suppose for every finite subextension $L_0/k$ we have $L_0\otimes_k K$ is a field, we want to show that $L\otimes_k K$ is a field as well. First, WLOG ${\rm tr.deg}(L/k)$ is finite. Take $X$ to be a proper normal integral scheme over $k$ with rational function field $L$.   We know ${\rm H}^0(X,\mathcal{O}_X)=L_0$ is a finite extension of $k$. Then ${\rm H}^0(X_K, \mathcal{O}_{X_K})=L_0\otimes_k K$ is a field by our assumption which implies that $X_K$ is connected. But $X$ is normal implies that $X_K$ is also normal. Then $X_K$ is both normal and connected hence integral. Now, ${\rm Spec}(L\otimes_k K)$ is nothing but the rational function field of $X_K$.